# Android: changing view on orientation change

Tags: android, xml, surfaceview

I am writing a physics simulator where in portrait mode, a custom surface view is displayed followed by several sliders that adjust parameters controlling the animation, i.e., physical parameters such as drag coefficient, all of which are defined in an XML file. When the user changes to orientation to landscape, I want the custom surface view to take up the entire screen. Is there someway to detect an orientation change and change the display instead of adjusting the same one?

Comment: you can have two folders in your **res** folder, one for landscape called **layout-land** and the other for portrait called **layout**. they should have the same files names for each activity that you want it to have different views in landscape and portrait. for instance, if your layout's name is "ball", you would have `ball.xml` in your **layout** folder and `ball.xml` in  your **layout-land** folder.This way the android OS will automatically detect which orientation the application is in right now and render the corresponding xml file

Comment: hmmm it's causing a null-pointer exception somehow. might just have something to do with my surface view class though

Comment: you will have a null pointer exception if your landscape layout doesn't have all the elements of your portail layout. that way, in your java activity you would be requesting a view in R.id.somehing that doesnt exist in landscape xml. try to identify all your views in both layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes surely you have. In the res folder, make a new folder named "layout-land" and in that folder put the desired xml file.

Comment: hmmm it's causing a null-pointer exception somehow. might just have something to do with my surface view class though

Comment: If possible put the xml and java file code here so that we can manually check them.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this page [Handling the Configuration Change Yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) .There you can add some `android:configChange` property to your manifest file and use the function [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) .